# Delaying multiple shots on a single mouse click Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to have a target shoot a series of shots based off a single action (currently just a mouse click) I'm pretty new to C# and Unity so I was hoping someone could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shooting : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject bullet;
    public GameObject bulletSpawn;
    public float fireRate;
    private Transform _bullet;
   

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            Fire(); 
    }

    public IEnumerator Fire()
    {
        for (int x = 1; x <= 9; x++)
        {
           
            _bullet = Instantiate(bullet.transform, bulletSpawn.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I currently have and any help (and explanation if your time allows) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am curious: what made you use the `yield return` syntax? If you just make a normal loop I think that would be a good start.

Comment: I was trying to yield because 1. I'm still new and thats what was a recommendation to try on random posts elsewhere. 2. because when I do the for loop it shoots them all pretty much at the exact same time. I would like it to look like a natural machine gun that would fire 10 bullets slightly spaced out.

Answer (score 2):

Coroutine needs to be started with StartCoroutine.

```
public void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        StartCoroutine(Fire()); 
}
```

A secondary issue may rise from this, you are about to shoot 9 bullets at 1s interval so 9 sec (your loop starts from 1 to 9, starts from 0 if you want 10). You either need to prevent a new run or cancel the current one to start a new one.

Option 1 :

```
 private bool isRunning = false;

public void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && isRunning == false)
    {
        isRunning = true;
        StartCoroutine(Fire());
    } 
}

public IEnumerator Fire()
{
    for (int x = 1; x <= 9; x++)
    {
       
        _bullet = Instantiate(bullet.transform, bulletSpawn.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    }
    isRunning = false;
}
```

Option 2:

```
private IEnumerator coroutine;

public void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        if(coroutine != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(coroutine);
        }
        coroutine = Fire();
        StartCoroutine(coroutine);
    } 
}

public IEnumerator Fire()
{
    for (int x = 1; x <= 9; x++)
    {
       
        _bullet = Instantiate(bullet.transform, bulletSpawn.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    }
    coroutine = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

is that what you want?
this code will Instantiate one bullet every second
tell me in the comment what customization you need

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shooting : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject bullet;
    public GameObject bulletSpawn;
    public float fireRate;
    private Transform _bullet;
    int x = 0;
    bool distouch = true;

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && distouch)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Fire());
            x = 0;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator Fire()
    {
        if (x < 10)
        {
           x++;
           distouch = false;
            _bullet = Instantiate(bullet.transform, bulletSpawn.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
            StartCoroutine(Fire());
        }else{
            distouch = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, the only thing that happens that I don't really understand why is that it shoots 12 shots instead of just 10 or 11 as would be expected. I can change the numbers around to make it only shoot the desired number, but I would like to know the REASON it shoots 12 instead of only 10 or 11.

Comment: cuz we need to disable touch until the 10 shots done, I gonna edit the answer right now also I have started from 0 to 11, if the count = 11, set x = 1;

Comment: I was able to get it to work, however, is it supposed to be x == 10? It seems like it doesn't works anymore that way.

Comment: sorry make it <, i forget to change it

Comment: Ok that’s what I thought I just wanted to make sure I wasn’t missing anything haha! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

your idea was good but you forgot to start the coroutine, so change

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            Fire();
```

to:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        StartCoroutine(Fire());
```

this way you start the coroutine and the function returns every second

edit: as fafase is saying you need to make sure that the coroutine doesn't get started multiple times.